# How to automatically remove space before punctuation and adding after sign?

Tags: spacing, punctuation

Sometimes when I write some text, I mistakingly put space before dot/comma or I forget to put space after dot/comma. I would like LaTeX to remove all space before dots and add space after punctuation.

For example:

"This is some text . This is some text"

should be

"This is some text. This is some text"

and

"This is some text.This is some text"

should be

"This is some text. This is some text"

I'm from Europe.

Comment: It would be easier to perform that search/replace in your editor, rather than asking LaTeX to do it.  I should add that doing your proposed fix automatically would screw up all kinds of things, like decimal numbers, web addresses, etc.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes How can you do that with search and replace? I think that if you set an exception to ​​not automatically put the space on the punctuation followed and preceded by a number you deal with most of the cases in Which you do not need a space. Url are normally inside `\ url {}` not so difficult to deal with.

Comment: Searching and replacing can be done various ways, your standard LaTeX editor can do it, but placing exceptions might be difficult there. Don't replace all instances at ones, but confirm each match. With *sed*, *awk* or *perl* it could be done easier, but one has to know how to use them.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks I'm aware of search and replace but what `find command` can you use? Is there an unknown character in search and replace for searching something like this `*.*`?

Comment: Depends on the editor, OS ... In some environments, a single dot can be treated special.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes, so you can't find it.

Comment: @GM Would be horrible if one couldn't find a simple dot using a script. Try escaping with a backslash `\.` What needs to be done depends on the environment, as said before.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks a lot for the help, can you give me your solution with VIM,emacs, texmaker, texstudio or any of the most used latex editor? Of course find `"."`and substitute with `". "` is not very effective...

Comment: In Kile, for example, something like find '([^ 0-9]) *(\.) *([^ 0-9])' and replace '\1\2 \3' would do a reasonable job, though you'd still need to check each replacement to rule out e.g. inclusion within \url{}. sed or gawk would make things easier but probably only if you already use them. Note that this is fairly Kile-specific in that Kile treats unescaped brackets as grouping.

Comment: @cfr thanks this seems a good method, I don't have Kile to test but I imagine that it works. However I have to test it with all the punctuation "(),;.:" so I think an automatic spacing could be useful...

Comment: You can easily adapt it to catch stuff other than full-stops but you are going to run into even more things this would potentially mess up since commas and colons, for example, are frequently used in macros, as are brackets. It might be possible for *you* to devise something automatic but it will be much harder (maybe impossible) for anybody else to do so since they don't know which macros you use, for example, and so need to workaround.

Comment: @cfr yes my point was that I have to repeat the process with all the punctuations that needs space like `, ) ; : . ! ?` so is not so effective. Thanks a lot for the help however.

Comment: You don't have to run it separately, though. You just have to take account of the various possibilities when writing the regular expression you search for. So you can tell sed or the replace in your TeX editor to match all instances of such-and-such followed by (full-stop or left-bracket or question-mark or colon etc.) followed by so-and-so. You then tell it to replace each match by e.g. the-bit-of-punctuation-you-found followed by space or whatever.

Comment: @GM, latex is no substitute for a basic knowledge of regular expressions. You're trying to use a nuclear weapon to fry an egg. (i.e., forget scale, it's not even the right tool). To search for multiple types of punctuation, use the following version of `@cfr`'s regexp: `'([^ 0-9]) *([,);:.!?]) *([^ 0-9])'`, still with `\1\2 \3` as the replacement pattern. To do it in emacs, write grouping parentheses as `\(` and `\)`. To do anything else, _learn_ about your editor's regular expression features. It'll be time well spent.

Comment: As many others recoomend you before, this problem is something you may fix in your own editor, but perhaps not automatically. Remember that you can put one or 50 spaces between words within a paragraph and LaTeX put only one in the final layout after compile. But LaTeX isn't able to know if you miss a space between words. That's why @Johannes_B says is hard to do a script for that.

The solution is easy: *read your document once compiled, then you can find mistakes*. There is not a better solution or method.

Comment: This is a task for Regular Expressions. You may look how your editor handles it. To test your sintaxes this site https://regexr.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's try a *slacky* trick.

### Ingredients

For our next trick we will need:

1. [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) editor installed (don't worry is multiplatform),
2. A package (for this editor) called [LaTeX Tools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) 
   installed in turn by
3. [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/) (A plugin or package that eases the installation of another packages).

### Preparation

Once you have all installed following the instructions in each case, then you can use `Sublime Text 2` as a LaTeX editor. I recommend, for convenience, use the color scheme called **Monokai Bright** (but you can experiment and use your favourite).

Open a single `.tex` file with Sublime Text 2 or load the directory of whole project (as you prefer). Once you have open your file, is easy search and replace what you need. Let's test:

1. Press `Ctrl + F`
2. In the bottom of the screen will appear a bar with the following options (from left to right):

   - Regular expressions (`Alt+R`)
   - Case sensitive (`Alt+C`)
   - Whole word (`Alt+W`)
   - Reverse direction
   - Wrap
   - In selection
   - Highlight matches

And a filed where you can input what are searching for. In our case will be `.` it means a dot with space before. Up here you can use the editor that you like for what I am suggesting. However Sublime Text 2 (and maybe emacs if you use  AucTeX) has a very interesting feature that, in my opinion, deserves their use for this task.

Well, from the above list, I suggest enable the options:

- Regular expresions (can be useful for this task),
- Whole word (avoid to select `...` by example if you have instead of `\ldots`) ,
- Reverse direction (to review until the end of the document and return to the beginning, if you start seeking half of it) and highlight matches (the reason for select Monokai bright instead of Monokai).

Now press `[Esc]` before activate the options. Search by ona incidence of `.` and with the cursor of the mouse select carefully both, the space before and the dot. The final trick is to make **multiple selections** from the selected effect, press for that now `Ctrl+D` holding the keys.

If the selection was well done, then **you can at the same time highlight the issues**, even better, **you'll have a real-time cursor in each and every one of the incidences detected**.

This is important because it allows you to **simultaneously edit all incidences**, and correct all by removing the extra space at once (Use the arrow keys left and right direction to move the cursor to the beginning or end of the selection. Use it in this case left arrow key and press `[Del]`).

Is not exactly automatic, is not an script, but it works very well.

### Remarks

Although there are programs and plugins to *translate* documents from Word to LaTeX and vice versa, I have not used any (almost all have licences and you must pay for them). Instead of that before I copied the text directly from Word and paste in Sublime Text 2 where I format it. Sometimes I prefer to open in AbiWord and export to LaTeX with a plugin included. But this plugin is almost experimental, and generates a lot of unnecessary code and not well placed some labels such as hierarchy ones (`\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, etc.). To correct these imbalances do use tricks like that tricks like that just explained, that allow me to debug the code with relative ease.

I hope this long and overdetailed explanation will be helpful.

Comment: I don't understand what the benefit is over just using a "search and replace all" method...?

Comment: To be honest and almost a decade later I don't think there is any substantial advantage, it is just a bad practice from a possibility that this text editor allows me to realise.

On hindsight, I consider that you can make use of the editor that best suits you and that's it, I guess it's time to review and edit this answer which, by the way, I didn't even remember writing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the original poster is still around, but this might come in handy for some people.

Please use with caution.

Although I tried to handle exclusion of delimiters inside control sequences or digital values, you still may occasionally need to manually disable the rule set when needed. (See the provided `\AutospaceOn`/`\AutospaceOff` switch. You can of course create finer-grained, *rule-by-rule* toggling instead.)

Also, **Autospace mode must not be in ON state when the document ends**, lest you should receive a `package logreq` **error**: make sure to use an `\AutospaceOff` at the end of the document.

Note: this collides with `pgfutil`:
if ever you use within `tikz` e.g. `postaction`, make sur to disable `Autospace` through `\AutospaceOff` beforehand and reactivate it afterwards through `\AutospaceOn`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}


\begin{luacode*}
    
function comma_space(s)
s = string.gsub(s, "[%s~]*,", ",")
s = string.gsub(s, ",(%a)", function(x)
if x == "\\footnote" or x == "\\footnotemark" then
return "," .. x
else
return ", " .. x
end
end)
return s
end

function period_space(s)
s = string.gsub(s, "(%.)[%s~]*(%D)", function(x, y)
if x == "\\footnote" or x == "\\footnotemark" or string.match(y, "%d") then
return x .. y
else
return x .. " " .. y
end
end)
return s
end

function colon_space(s)
s = string.gsub(s, "[%s~]*:", ":")
s = string.gsub(s, ":(%a)", function(x)
if x == "\\footnote" or x == "\\footnotemark" then
return ":" .. x
else
return ": " .. x
end
end)
return s
end

function semicolon_space(s)
s = string.gsub(s, "[%s~]*;", ";")
s = string.gsub(s, ";(%a)", function(x)
if x == "\\footnote" or x == "\\footnotemark" then
return ";" .. x
else
return "; " .. x
end
end)
return s
end

function quote_space(s)
s = string.gsub(s, "\"[%s~]+", "``")
s = string.gsub(s, "[%s~]+\"", "''")
s = string.gsub(s, "«([^%s~])", "«\\,%1")
s = string.gsub(s, "([^%s~])»", "%1\\,»")
return s
end

function autospace(line)
if string.sub(line, 1, 1) == "\\" then
local command = string.match(line, "\\(%w+)")
if string.sub(command, 1, 4) == "text" then
line = string.gsub(line, "(%s*)(%b{})", function(space, arg)
return space .. autospace(arg)
end)
end
else
line = comma_space(line)
line = period_space(line)
line = colon_space(line)
line = semicolon_space(line)
line = string.gsub(line, "[%s~]+(%p)", "%1")
line = quote_space(line)  
end
return line
end

\end{luacode*}


\newcommand{\AutospaceOn}{
    \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", autospace, "autospace")}
}

\newcommand{\AutospaceOff}{
    \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "autospace")}
}

% You may create more refined toggles, e.g. \AutoCommaspaceOn by adding specific functions such as comma_space instead of the global autospace function.    


\begin{document}
    
    
    \AutospaceOn
    
    \textit{"   This is a test,no space before the comma but space after .No space before the period but space after .And this is a test :no space before the colon but space after .And this is a test ; no space before the semicolon but should be after the semicolon .This is a test «for French quotes» .   "}
    
    
    \vspace{2.99ex} % As you can see, no undesirable space is added after the decimal point.
    
    \textbf{"   This is a test,no space before the comma but space after .No space before the period but space after .And this is a test :no space before the colon but space after .And this is a test ;\footnote{test} no space before the semicolon but should be after the semicolon .This is a test «for French quotes» .   "}
    
    \vspace{2.99ex} % As you can see, no undesirable space is added after the decimal point.
    
        This is a test,~no space added before a tilde;~no space:~no space.~No space.
    
    \vspace{2.99ex} % As you can see, no undesirable space is added after the decimal point.
    
    No space between punctuation and a footnote mark,\footnote{test} no space;\footnote{test} no space:\footnote{test} no space\footnote{test}.
    
    \vspace{2.99ex} % As you can see, no undesirable space is added after the decimal point.
    
    \AutospaceOff
    
    "   This is a test ,no space before the comma but space after .No space before the period but space after .\footnote{essai} And this is a test :\footnote{essai} no space before the colon but space after .And this is a test ;\footnote{essai} no space before the semicolon but should be after the semicolon .This is a test «for French quotes» .   " 
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Now if you want to avoid unwanted auto-spaces before `footnote` marks, and add support for tildes and text-formatting commands, the code should be modified the following way.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}


\begin{luacode*}
    
function comma_space(s)
s = string.gsub(s, "[%s~]*,", ",")
s = string.gsub(s, ",(%a)", function(x)
if x == "\\footnote" or x == "\\footnotemark" then
return "," .. x
else
return ", " .. x
end
end)
return s
end

function period_space(s)
s = string.gsub(s, "(%.)[%s~]*(%D)", function(x, y)
if x == "\\footnote" or x == "\\footnotemark" or string.match(y, "%d") then
return x .. y
else
return x .. " " .. y
end
end)
return s
end

function colon_space(s)
s = string.gsub(s, "[%s~]*:", ":")
s = string.gsub(s, ":(%a)", function(x)
if x == "\\footnote" or x == "\\footnotemark" then
return ":" .. x
else
return ": " .. x
end
end)
return s
end

function semicolon_space(s)
s = string.gsub(s, "[%s~]*;", ";")
s = string.gsub(s, ";(%a)", function(x)
if x == "\\footnote" or x == "\\footnotemark" then
return ";" .. x
else
return "; " .. x
end
end)
return s
end

function quote_space(s)
s = string.gsub(s, "\"[%s~]+", "``")
s = string.gsub(s, "[%s~]+\"", "''")
s = string.gsub(s, "«([^%s~])", "«\\,%1")
s = string.gsub(s, "([^%s~])»", "%1\\,»")
return s
end

function autospace(line)
if string.sub(line, 1, 1) == "\\" then
local command = string.match(line, "\\(%w+)")
if string.sub(command, 1, 4) == "text" then
line = string.gsub(line, "(%s*)(%b{})", function(space, arg)
return space .. autospace(arg)
end)
end
else
line = comma_space(line)
line = period_space(line)
line = colon_space(line)
line = semicolon_space(line)
line = string.gsub(line, "[%s~]+(%p)", "%1")
line = quote_space(line)  
end
return line
end

\end{luacode*}

\newcommand{\AutospaceOn}{
    \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", autospace, "autospace")}
}

\newcommand{\AutospaceOff}{
    \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "autospace")}
}

% You may create more refined toggles, e.g. \AutoCommaspaceOn by adding specific functions such as comma_space instead of the global autospace function.    


\begin{document}
    
    
    \AutospaceOn
    
\textit{"   This is a test ,no space before the comma but space after .No space before the period but space after .\footnote{test} And this is a test :\footnote{test} no space before the colon but space after .And this is a test ;\footnote{test} no space before the semicolon but should be after the semicolon .This is a test «for French quotes» .   "}

    \vspace{2.99ex} % As you can see, no undesirable space is added after the decimal point.

\textbf{"   This is a test ,no space before the comma but space after .No space before the period but space after .\footnote{test} And this is a test :\footnote{test} no space before the colon but space after .And this is a test ;\footnote{test} no space before the semicolon but should be after the semicolon .This is a test «for French quotes» .   "}
    
    \vspace{2.99ex} % As you can see, no undesirable space is added after the decimal point.
    
    \AutospaceOff
    
"   This is a test ,no space before the comma but space after .\footnote{essai}No space before the period but space after .\footnote{essai} And this is a test :\footnote{essai} no space before the colon but space after .And this is a test ;\footnote{essai} no space before the semicolon but should be after the semicolon .This is a test «for French quotes» .   " 
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It appears that the first three lines of code repeat themselves

Answer (score 0):

We vim users can't let sublime text users have all the fun.

It's fairly easy to set vim up so that whenever you type `.` or `,` it automatically gobbles up all the space before them, and automatically inserts a space afterwards.

```
inoremap <silent> . <Esc>v^:s/\s*$//<CR>:nohls<CR>`>a.<Space>
inoremap <silent> , <Esc>v^:s/\s*$//<CR>:nohls<CR>`>a,<Space>
```

If you only want that to apply to .tex files then put it in `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex/tex.vim` (or `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/tex/tex.vim` for neovim). If you want it to apply to all documents, then it goes in `~/.vimrc` (or `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` for neovim).

If you need to add a space beforehand or remove a space after, for things like decimals, urls, etc., you can still do so if you do it afterwards.

The only downside is that if you type a period or comma but then actually do remember to put a space in afterwards, you'll end up with two spaces. You can prevent that by having `<Space>` double check whether or not it's following `.`  or `,`  and disable itself when it is:

```
function SpaceOrNoSpace()
    let c=col('.')
    if (c==1) || (c==2)
        return ' '
    endif
    let p=strpart(getline('.'),c-3,2)
    if (p=='. ') || (p==', ')
        return ''
    endif
    return ' '
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <Space> SpaceOrNoSpace()
```

And course if you have document that's already written that you need to fix, it's easy to search for all spaces before `,` and `.`, or non-spaces afterwards, and fix them:

To remove spaces before them:

```
:%s/ \([.,]\)/\1/gc
```

To add spaces after them:

```
:%s/\([.,]\)\(\S\)/\1 \2/gc
```

(The `c` at the end means you'll have to confirm each one; If you don't want to confirm them, leave the `c` out.)

I can't imagine actually doing this myself, but it's fun to think about.